# $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that there doesn't exist any Lipschitz continuous function $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with following property: The curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\gamma(t)=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$ is a solution curve to differential equation $\dot{\gamma}(t)=X(\gamma(t)).$

This was as an exercise in previous exam in Analysis 2. But, in my all efforts I was capable to show that such a function $X$ is in fact Lipschitz-continuous. I have used the fact $\dot{\gamma}(t)=\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}=X(\gamma(t))$ and by definition of Lipschitz continuity this was in fact bounded for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if I understood real problem or not but I need your help for this question.

Comment: Should this be tagged with `(lipschitz-functions)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such a function $X$ exists with Lipschitz constant $C>0.$ Then by the definition of Lipschitz continuity, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we must have
$$\frac{2t}{(1+t^{2})^{2}} \leq C\frac{t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}.$$
Then, rearranging, for all $t\neq0$ we have $0\leq Ct^{3}-Ct^{2}-2.$ But at $t=0$ we have $Ct^{3}-Ct^{2}-2=-2<-1,$ and then there would be no point $t$ where the cubic is equal to $-1,$ contradicting the Intermediate Value Theorem (the polynomial is clearly continuous on, say, the interval $[-1,1]$).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $X$ is $k$ Lipshcitz.

$$\dot \gamma(t) = |\dot \gamma(t) - \dot \gamma(0)| = |X(\gamma(t))- X(\gamma(0))| \le k|\gamma(t) - \gamma(0)| = k \gamma(t)$$

Impossible since this implies that for all $t\neq 0$, $kt^3 + kt - 2 \ge 0$, while $kt^3 + kt - 2 \to -\infty$ as $t \to - \infty$